# apache drill memory exception

Tags: parquet, apache-drill

I am trying to reformat over 600gb of csv files into parquet using apache drill in a single node setup.

I run my sql statement:

```
CREATE TABLE AS Data_Transform.'/' AS
....
FROM Data_source.'/data_dump/*'
```

and it is creating parquet files but I get the error:

```
Query Failed: An Error Occurred
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: RESOURCE ERROR:     
One or more nodes ran out of memory while executing the query.
```

is there a way around this?
Or is there an alternative way to do the conversion?

Comment: Are you using select * ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if querying all those GB on a local node is feasible. If you've configured the memory [per the docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-drill-memory/), using a cluster of Drillbits to share the load is the obvious solution, but I guess you already know that.

If you're willing to experiment, and you're converting csv files using a select * to query the csv, rather than selecting individual columns, change the query to something like select columns[0] as user_id, columns[1](https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-drill-memory/) as user_name. Cast any columns to types like int, float, datetime if possible. This avoids the read overhead storing data in the varchars and prepares data for your future queries that need to be cast for any analysis.

I've also seen the following recommendation from a Drill developer: split files into smaller files manually to overcome the local file system capability limitations. Drill doesn't split files on block splits.

Comment: I stuck with one local node for the forseeable future due to IT policies at work. I have used CAST as well. the files range from a few kb to x00 MB. Is there some loop convert function?

Comment: No loop convert function afaik, sorry.